# Overloading operator body contains only one function call

Tags: c++, c++11

I have this function

```
int add(T a, T b)
{
  return a.blah +b.blah;
}
```

And I want to overload the plus operator and I have to options (*of course, in this case the plus operator already accomplishes what the following code does*)

**Option 1:**

```
int operator+(T lhs, T rhs)
{
  return add(a,b);
}
```

**Option 2:**

```
int operator+(T lhs, T rhs)
{
  return a.blah+b.blah;
}
```

Does any of those definitions have a performance edge over the other? Something to not is that the function I am trying to implement performs a more complicated operation on the elements of an STL container.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I clearly said 
"of course, in this case the plus operator already accomplishes what the following code does."

Comment: Well, if you could do this then option 2 is not an option as it would be a infinite recursive call.

Comment: _the plus operator already accomplishes_ is something different to _you can't overload operators for built in types_, isnt it?

Comment: Don't use built-in types for illustrative purposes. That's just confusing. Use an enumeration instead. Then the code will make sense when coupled with the question.

Comment: Chance are the 2 will be compiled in same code after sufficient optimization flag.

Comment: DRY and use Option 1, especially if it's a more complicated operation. If you're concerned about performance and the objects might be big, consider passing them as `const T&`.

Comment: Some advice: Don't worry about optimizing every line of code.  Write the code the is natural and easy to understand.  The compile with optimizations on and profile.  If the performance is acceptable then your done.  You'd be surprised how much the compiler can optimize these days, especially if the code is not obscure.

Comment: What about Option 3: rename `int add(T a, T b)` to `int operator+(T lhs, T rhs)`?

Comment: @Caleth Backward compatibility. That would've been the solution that made sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use option 1, do not repeat yourself. Make sure the compiler sees the definition of add when you define operator+ so it can inline the code. There will be absolutely no difference in the generated code when optimizations are turned on.

```
struct T
{
    int blah;
};

int add(T a, T b)
{
  return a.blah +b.blah;
}

int operator+(T lhs, T rhs)
{
  return add(lhs, rhs);
}
```

GCC generates:

```
add(T, T):
  lea eax, [rdi+rsi]
  ret
operator+(T, T):
  lea eax, [rsi+rdi]
  ret
```

https://godbolt.org/g/g1ypni

Clang and the Microsoft compiler generate the same code.

If the code is more complex and the compiler refuses to inline `add` into `operator+`, consider making operator+ an inline function. Then it will get inlined since it does just one call and the caller will directly call `add` without additional overhead.

The usual admonition: You should of course as always benchmark to see if there is any real difference and profile to see what is causing the difference, also look at the generated code to check whether optimizations are performed as you expect :-)

Answer (score 1):

Option 1 is better as you are not duplicating code.

Might be better still to pass T by constant reference to obviate a value copy.